# User logged in with temporary profile

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, user-profile

User logs into a domain-joined Windows 7 Pro PC and gets the temporary profile error pop-up.

Event 1511 User Profile Service in Event Viewer logs.

Typically with this problem I delete a user's registry key folder under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList, however in this instance the user is not even listed here.

Are there any other ways to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Does the problem only happen when THAT user logs on? Any issue if DIFFERENT user logs on? I've seen this warning when there are keys beneath Profilefile that end with ".bak". Removing the bak's fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

These are all guesses, but:

- Is there anything weird going on with the NTFS permissions in users?
- Is C:\Users\Default corrupted?
- Is the disk full?
- Is there something weird going on with the registry permissions in
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
  NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList?

Lastly,

- Is it your antivirus?  [Microsoft says](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947215), "Occasionally, Windows might not read your user profile correctly, such as if your antivirus software is scanning your computer while you try to log on."

Hopefully, one of those will help you out.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll get another crack at this PC next week.